# Xcode workspaces build process

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to Xcode workspaces but I basically have my main UI project, and a couple of small utility libraries that I am starting to build.  The problem I'm having is I need to build the utility framework first before I build the main UI library again.

That's usually fine if I don't have to make changes to the utility library, but it is a bit annoying.  Is there a way for Xcode workspaces that when you build one target, it'll automatically build the other two dependent libraries?

Comment: If you make this a framework _of_ the main app, it will have this dependency _automatically_.

Comment: @matt how do you make it a framework of the main app?  Do you mean add it in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"?  I have it in there, but it still requires me to build the framework first before building the UI project.

Comment: I mean start by adding a framework target to your app project. Now the framework is _part_ of the app.

Comment: @matt so is this different than having it as a workspace?

Comment: I believe that is the entire point of my suggestion. This would just be an ordinary app project containing some frameworks. Maybe you have some reason for not doing that, but so far you have not said so...

Comment: @matt I'm not super familiar with either approach to be honest.  I just thought that Apple was pushing using workspaces on reading some blog vs embedded projects.  No real reason other than that.  Not sure which one is better.  Thanks.

Comment: But what I'm saying is, since you don't know how to configure a dependency, you might like a solution where everything is set up for you automatically.